# How to approximate the sum of number of divisors from 1 to n?

Tags: algorithm, approximation, number-theory

#### The Problem

I want to solve this problem:

Let the number of divisors = d(n) (for example, d(6)=4 because number 6 has 4 divisors, {1, 2, 3, 6}), I want to calculate d(1)+d(2)+d(3)+...+d(n).

But I can't calculate for large n like 10^20 or 10^30 (I think the algorithm calculting in a few seconds if n is as large as 10^30 doesn't exist), so I decided to find the algorithm that calculates **approximately**.

#### My Current Solution

I found that the answer is near by n log n (the base of log is e=2.71828...)

But in case of n = 10^17 the error is about 0.4%. 

It's a little accurate, but I think that there are more accurate algorithm.

Is there any more accurate algorithm?

Comment: Of course the algorithm _exists_.

Comment: @JoshLee What means? Do you know the algorithm of solving d(1)+d(2)+...+d(n) in few seconds, deterministically?

Comment: Without any constraints on the size of n, run time, or storage requirements, the algorithm for "Sum of divisors of n" is the same for small n and large n. Saying, for example, that the naive algorithm takes exponential time, would clarify what you mean.

Comment: @JoshLee Little edited my question. n is about 10^30

Comment: The Haskell code at https://oeis.org/A000203 seems plenty fast to me.

Comment: @JoshLee I don't know Haskell much, so please tell me the algorithm... (it seems the code includes like a027748_row array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Number_of_divisors) credits the estimate

```
n log n + (2γ - 1)n + O(√n)
```

to Dirichlet (1849). γ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). You can just drop the O(√n) error term.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function). Also, https://oeis.org/A006218.